# How do I avoid crashes when using xlwings? It crashes on xw.App()

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Im trying to make a simple sheet calculating the summation of two numbers: A3 = A1 + A2. I use the script below.

```
import xlwings as xw


app = xw.App(visible=False)

wb = xw.Book(r'C:/Data/xlwings/testxlwings.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]
sh.range("A1").value = 683
sh.range("A2").value = 14
A3 = sh.range("A3").value
print(A3)
wb.save()
app.kill()
```

On one machine, this works perfectly and get the desired result of 697.0. On my other (virtual) machine I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Data\xlwings\xlwingssdemo.py", line 11, in <module>
    app = xw.App(visible=False)

  File "C:\Users\POuser1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.impl = xlplatform.App(spec=spec, add_book=add_book)

  File "C:\Users\POuser1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 290, in __init__
    self._xl.Workbooks.Add()

  File "C:\Users\POuser1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 63, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Add

com_error: (-2146827284, 'OLE error 0x800a03ec', None, None)
```

I tried:

1. reinstalling Python
2. making sure all modules are same version
3. trying every google link I could find

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is Excel installed on the virtual machine?

Comment: It is installed and functional.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to solve the problem, but new lines are not allowed in comments, therefore I write this as answer.
I would check if python has access to excel (by using the COM interface). Therefore, open a excel workbook on your virtual machine and execute the following code in python:

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
print(f"If a running Excel instance found, return the object:\n{excel}")
```

If this code runs without an error while excel is open, you know at least that python has access to excel.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sadly, that code crashes as well with an error I cannot show you anymore. I managed to "fix" this issue by a complete reinstall of Windows. My problem is solved, but the issue might prevail.